# cakephp interpretation on different hosts

Tags: mysql, cakephp, x86, 64-bit

i have 2 pc hosts where i develop some application in cakephp.

one is 64bit and another is 32 bit win 7 OS. on both computers is installed WAMP server, pc 32bit is WAMP 32bit and on pc 64bit is installed WAMP 64bit.

i have some differences in interpreting php pages. On 64x i have problem with input decimal numbers and when i migrate database and app directory to 32 bit PC, number input works fine.

In database i have field decimal(6,2), and in form:
-on 32 bit PC input field works fine. when i input for example 3,124554 i get red warning to round number to 3,12 or 3,13. or when i input 3,12 it works fine.. it saves number. (WITH COMMA) - > it works

-on 64x, identical database and application, when i input 3,12 - > in fact when i input decimal number with coma i get message-> please enter a number, BUT when i insert something with dot (.) it saves a number.

-regional settings are same on both hosts (decimal simbol is ,->comma). 
-php, apacehe and mysql versions are identical. 
-in both hosts i use firefox (same version)

Server version: 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12

is it possible that 32 and 64 bits could gave different results in browsers?
any idea what can i try more?

thank you

i tried next.
1. - On 64x pc i put WAMP server online and i connected to these app with another machine and app works ok. i can save decimals without errors. it is unbelievably to me because (i think) php server must work on all platforms same.

2. - on 32x PC i put server WAMP online i tried to insert a field from my 64x lenovo pc, but i cant. browser doesnt give me to save.

strange, but maybe will help to someone.

Comment: You're using the same browser on the same computer to access both web servers?  To rule out browser differences in how they handle javascript, assuming your "red warning" is from js.

Comment: same browsers version, firefox 40.0.2 on different computers. it s javascript.. app is baked with cake. and only thing what has sense is that it hapens becouse of 32-64x win or 32-64x WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with HTML requirement:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```